# How to get month length into a Gridview in Flutter from DateTime

Tags: flutter

I have `Gridview.builder` which returns the days of a `weekIndex`.

I need to display the length of the current month in order to show only the days associated with that month and I don't know what to put into `itemCount`.

This is my code:

```
GridView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 7,
  ),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder:
      (BuildContext context, int index) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    int milliseconds = now
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch -
        (now.weekday - 1) *
            24 *
            60 *
            60 *
            1000 +
        index * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 +
        index * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    DateTime dayDateTime =
    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        milliseconds);
    int monthIndex = dayDateTime.month - 1;
    List months = [
      'Gen',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'Mag',
      'Giu',
      'Lug',
      'Ago',
      'Set',
      'Ott',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ];
    List weekdays = WeekDays.days;
    String month = months[monthIndex];
    String day = dayDateTime.day.toString();
    String weekday =
    weekdays[dayDateTime.weekday - 1];
    String date =
        weekday + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
    String theDay = day + ' ' + weekday;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        toggleIndex(index);
        confirmed = true;
      },
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: selectionIndexes.contains(index) ? Colors.purple: Colors.white,
        shape: now.weekday ==
            index + 1 &&
            index == 0 ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: new BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange, width: 2.0),):RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: new BorderSide(
              color: Colors.orange, width: 0),),
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
                theDay,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: selectionIndexes.contains(index)? Colors.white : Colors.black87)
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

At the moment I hard-coded 20 as the `itemCount` but I need the dynamic value to show the real current month's length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of remaining days for the current month, we first need to get the last day of the month:

```
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);
```

And then subtract the current date:

```
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);
Duration difference = lastDayOfMonth.difference(now);
```

In order to get an `int`, which represents the number of days, we can use the `inDays` property of `Duration`:

```
difference.inDays // int, the number of days
```

Therefore, wrapping into a function:

```
int remainingDaysOfTheMonth() {
   DateTime now = DateTime.now();
   DateTime lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0);
   Duration difference = lastDayOfMonth.difference(now);
   return difference.inDays;
}
```

You could use it to set the `itemCount` into your `GridView`:

```
GridView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 7,
  ),
  itemCount: remainingDaysOfTheMonth(),
  itemBuilder:
      (BuildContext context, int index) { }
)
```

Comment: you can tell me also how to find the same but for the week?

Comment: I'd recommend posting another question with this specific scenario

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are looking to find out the number of days in a given month?

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();
DateTime monthEnd = DateTime(today.year, today.month + 1, 0); //This will give you last date of the month
int noOfDays = monthEnd.day;
```

There is probably easier solution. But this should work

Comment: ok but what to use into itemCount as lenght?

Comment: If you look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html (documentation), itemCount is not mandatory. But it improves the performance of GridView. If your GridView is returning a GridView widget per day in a month, use noOfDays above

Comment: you dont understand check the picture: https://ibb.co/zHVYfMm
As you can see below the month I have a GridView which need an Item count that should be the lenght of the current Month.